# How do you push a UI update to a javascript frontend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm building a simple react app that fetches a bunch of images and displays them as cards.

The intention is to show an info message until all the images have loaded, then removing the notice again.

```
const App = () => {
  const [cardInfo, setCardInfo] = useContext(CardInfoContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(setCardInfo)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const app = document.querySelector('.app')
    for(const child of app.children){
      app.removeChild(child)
    }

    const loadingNotice = document.createElement('h1')
    loadingNotice.innerHTML = "Fetching data ..."
    app.appendChild(loadingNotice) //<-- this never shows up

    cardInfo.forEach( info => {
      const img = document.createElement('img')
      img.src = info.image
      app.appendChild(img)
    })

    app.removeChild(loadingNotice)

  }, [cardInfo])
  
  return (
    <>
      <div className="app">
        <h1>Fetching data...</h1>
      </div>
    </>
)};
```

What instead happens is the app stays blank until all the images are loaded, then shows all the images at once -- but never the loading notice.

Can I somehow "push" the loading indicator change to the UI independent of the rest of the rendering?

Another thing I tried was

```
const App = () => {
  const [cardInfo, setCardInfo] = useContext(CardInfoContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(setCardInfo)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const app = document.querySelector('.app')
    if(!cardInfo) return

    const loadingNotice = app.querySelector(".loadingNotice")
    loadingNotice.style.display = 'block' //<-- this never shows up

    cardInfo.forEach( info => {
      const img = document.createElement('img')
      img.src = info.image
      app.appendChild(img)
    })

    loadingNotice.style.display = 'none'

  }, [cardInfo])
  
  return (
    <>
      <div className="app">
        <h1 className="loadingNotice">Fetching data...</h1>
      </div>
    </>
)}
```

Which would be incorrect because I do need to remove all the images, at least, but even that only displayed the loading notice for a fraction of a second, then the component goes blank until all the images can be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` observes when `cardInfo` is changed, not when the render the comes after fired. You can use [`useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) instead.

> ...but it fires synchronously after all DOM mutations. Use this to read layout from the DOM and synchronously re-render. Updates scheduled inside useLayoutEffect will be flushed synchronously, before the browser has a chance to paint.

BTW, I wouldn't combine direct DOM manipulation with React to avoid issues like this (among other reasons)

Something like

```js
const App = () => {
  const [isLoadgin, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [cardInfo, setCardInfo] = useContext(CardInfoContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(result => {
      setCardInfo(result);
      setIsLoading(false);
    })
  }, [])
    
  return (
    <>
      <div className="app">
        {isLoading && <h1 className="loadingNotice">Fetching data...</h1>}
        {
          cardInfo.map(card => <img src={card.image} />)
        }
      </div>
    </>
)}
```

Comment: Well if you wouldn't combine direct DOM manipulation with react, what would you use instead?

Comment: Use React :) If I understand correctly what your code aims to do, the following code should work - https://gist.github.com/moshfeu/406ee08315f6cc5b83707f1b8cd019a6

Comment: Much nicer, BUT it still doesn't show the loading indication, I'm afraid.

Comment: If you'd create a codesandbox so I could see the issue a live, it will be much easier for me to help.

Answer (score 0):

You need conditional rendering instead of all that DOM manipulation you are trying in the useEffect.

```
...
return(
<>
  <div className="app">
    { !cardInfo ? <h1 className="loadingNotice">Fetching data...</h1> : <Cards info={cardInfo} /> }

  </div>
</>

)
```

Note: I am assuming you have something like `<Cards>` component that displays cards details.